# How to prevent module's run block from being executed during testing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-ngmock

I'm trying to unit test a service provided by an angular module I've created, however I'm struggling to find a way to do so without also invoking the module's run block when it is loaded in. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

"Run blocks typically contain code which is hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests." [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

But I guess you could use Jasmine's spy to [SpyOn](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Spies) .run and return some fake function (e.g. angular.noop()).

Hope this helps :)